# gdalwarp leaves black boundary of cropped GeoTIFF with cutline

Tags: gdalwarp

This is a new question based on a response on the thread  [white page border when converting geoPDF to geoTiff with gdal_translate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182448)

I am using gdalwarp as described to do a cutline of GeoTIFF images that have been rendered from geospatial PDFs. The neatline in the PDFs is not accurate but I can easily create UTM coordinates and adjust them accordingly to get the GeoTIFF image that I desire.

This is the CSV file. The coordinates are not square

```
id,WKT
1,"POLYGON ((410290.5552 4025996.01,410434.6684 4039895.26,421656.358 4039786.037,421530.3048 4025886.935,410290.5552 4025996.01))"
```

This is the command line:

```
gdalwarp original.tif original.crop.tif -cutline mycutline.csv -crop_to_cutline
```

The new image is square and the cropped image is canted inside as is expected. The problem is that the outer crop area is showing up as black. When I tile the image and display it on top of a map base layer, it aligns perfectly except that it has a black edge around it. If the edging was transparent then it would be fine, but the when tiled, it definitely retains the black color.

Here is a sample image
http://www.appalachianbiketrails.org/images/resized.tif

Here is the tile example
http://www.appalachianbiketrails.org/tiles/openlayers.html

I have tried adding the -dstalpha flag as mentioned in other posts and shown in the code snippet below, but that gives the error "Cannot compute bounding box of cutline."

```
gdalwarp original.tif original.crop.tif -cutline mycutline.csv -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha
```

On a side note, I found that the direction of the coordinates in my CSV file determined whether the crop was inside or outside of the coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried `-dstnodata 0`?

Comment: It gives the error "Cannot compute bounding box of cutline." which is what I get when I use -dstalpha.

Comment: I would have a try with some other format than .csv for the cutline. Convert it into for example shapefile and add the info about the projection with -a_srs and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this via search, note the NEATLINE (as obtained from gdalinfo) in many (all?) USGS quad PDFs are incorrect, being larger than the correct NEATLINE  (still true in 2020 as of this post). Is why above did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues clipping using a CSV cutline - not sure if that's the issue here.

The USGS maps are nicely aligned to lat/lon, so I just created a GeoJSON cutline file ("usgs_bounds.geojson") and set the co-ordinates in that eg:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{
   "name":"TN_Shady_Valley_20160503_TM_geo"},
   "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-81.875,36.5],[-81.875,36.625],[-82,36.625],[-82,36.5],[-81.875,36.5]]]}}
]}
```

You can then run gdalwarp with a fairly similar command line:

- The -dstalpha option is the critical one - that's what will make the edging transparent
- The -cwhere option is completely unnecessary, because there is only one feature. However, if you set up multiple features in the GeoJSON file, you can run a script which will clip multiple maps
- EPSG:32617 is UTM Zone 17N - but can be set to any convenient CRS

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:32617 -r cubic -cutline "usgs_bounds.geojson" -cwhere "name = 'TN_Shady_Valley_20160503_TM_geo'" -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha "TN_Shady_Valley_20160503_TM_geo.tif" "TN_Shady_Valley_20160503_TM_geo_clip.tif"
```

[This was done using the 2016 Shady Valley map from USGS, which appears to be what the original poster was using]